# How do I disable the Sails v0.12 default CORS hook?

Tags: cors, sails.js, hook

The sails.js([SailsJs CORS](https://0.12.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/cors)) website says that the Sails CORS hook is disabled by default, but I am currently working with a code base, where it seems to be enabled. I want to disable the same but I cannot find an answer on Stack Overflow, as well as on other sites to this. I also researched the Sails page to begin with, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is as follows:

1. Navigate to `app_home_dir/.sailssrc`
2. You will find this `JSON` object there there:

   ```
   {
     "generators": {
     "modules": {}
     },
     "hooks": {
       "blueprints": false,
       "views": false,
       "sockets": false,
       "pubsub": false,
       "i18n": false,
       "cors": true
     }
   }
   ```
3. Modify the `cors` property and set it to `false`.

This will disable the default Sails CORS hook.